# Wrap-around detection

Tags: python, overflow

Suppose you have a list of values in increasing order, except that at some point they wrap-wround

```
2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 15, 34, -2, 1, 4, 5, 7, ...
```

Knowing that the period is 2^n, for some value of n, is there any built-in function, or a fast way to rearrange the values above so that all numbers are in increasing order (assuming the numbers are such that it is possible)?

Comment: Are there so many numbers that just plain old sorting the list doesn't work?

Comment: Do note that if you have a generator (and not a list as you say), with a potentially infinite number of values, it is impossible because you can never know if you are still in the first sequence.

Comment: @ninjagecko Huh? As soon as the values decrease, you know you've switched sequences.

Comment: @Dougal: oops, I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: @Bob: What do you mean by "the period"?

Comment: suppose you have [1,2,3,4,5] with period 6. If you shift the elements by 2, the last element becomes less then the others (modulo arithmetic). I would like to arrange a list such that this is not the case.

Comment: Oh, that's a completely different problem than everyone understood it to be. Do you have way to tell how much the period is, or should we just use the smallest power of two that works?

Comment: yeah, you could say the period  is 2^n for some value of n. let's assume 2^n is given.

Answer (score 5):

`list.sort()` might be fast enough. In CPython it is implemented using [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which should handle cases like your in a better-than-average way (the first stage is looking for already sorted runs of numbers exactly like in your case).

Comment: Indeed, Timsort's best-case performance occurs in exactly this sort of situation. Sorting here should be pretty close to O(n).

Comment: I don't need sorting. -2 and all subsequent numbers should become greater than 34

Comment: @Bob, please then rephrase your question. "rearrange" clearly suggest you wanted to just permute values, not change them. For example please provide an example output for your input.

Answer (score 2):

An expected output would help in understanding your question. I have guessed a different desired solution than others. Maybe someone else can find a more concise solution for this interpretation.

The output would be 
2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 15, 34, 62, 65, 68, 69, ...
i.e. all values starting from -2 are shifted up by 64

First I guess the period size 64. This could be done e.g. by looking at the most negative difference of neighbour elements and rounding up to a power of 2. This might not be possible if you dont have all values available in the beginning.

```
period = 64

def unwrap(seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    try:
        lastitem = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    yield lastitem
    shift = 0
    for item in it: 
        if item < lastitem:
            shift += period
        yield item + shift
        lastitem = item
```

If you need a list and not a generator you can use

```
result = list(unwrap(original_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want *all* of the values to be in increasing order, that's a sort:

```
>>> sorted([2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 15, 34, -2, 1, 4, 5, 7])
[-2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 12, 15, 34]
```

Are you trying to optimize the sort based on the knowledge it's consecutive numbers wrapping at intervals, or asking a different question?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sorted([5, 2, 3, 1, 4])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

>>> a = [5, 2, 3, 1, 4]
>>> a.sort()
```